# Jasmine test for ActivatedRoute Angular 7

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-activatedroute

I am trying to write a simple test for `ActivatedRoute`. Here's what my test looks like.

```
it("should check if subscribes are called in init", () => {
    const subRouteSpy = spyOn(activatedRouteStub.paramMap, "subscribe");
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(subRouteSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

My `TestBed  config`:

```
const activatedRouteStub = {
  paramMap: {
    subscribe() {
      return of();
    }
  }
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [HomeFilterDrawerComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub }
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers),
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    RouterTestingModule
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

The test keeps failing giving me `Expected spy subscribe to have been called.` Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong here.

The code inside `ngOnInit` of the component.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  if (params["params"].slug !== undefined) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular is cloning your `activatedRouteStub` object when you provide it via `useValue`. So you're spying on the original stub object, but your component sees a cloned object without the spy attached.

This is [mentioned in the guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing#always-get-the-service-from-an-injector)

> Always get the service from an injector Do not reference the
>   userServiceStub object that's provided to the testing module in the
>   body of your test. It does not work! The userService instance injected
>   into the component is a completely different object, a clone of the
>   provided userServiceStub.

To fix this, you need to get a reference to the cloned object using `TestBed.get`

```
let activatedRoute;

const activatedRouteStub = {
  paramMap: {
    subscribe() {
      return of();
    }
  }
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [HomeFilterDrawerComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteStub }
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers),
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    RouterTestingModule
  ]
}).compileComponents();

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewsComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // Get a reference to the injected value
  activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
});

it("should check if subscribes are called in init", () => {
  // Spy on the injected value
  const subRouteSpy = spyOn(activatedRoute.paramMap, "subscribe");
  component.ngOnInit();
  expect(subRouteSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Alternatively, you can keep your code the same, but change `useValue` to `useFactory`. This will allow you to bypass the cloning behavior:

```
providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useFactory: () => activatedRouteStub }]
```

Comment: This was awesome, good shout. For anyone else, use can use the above solution for the `data` property as well.